# iframe-style div with content bigger than the div itself

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `<div>` with a really long height (2000px, more or less) and I want to only show some of it (400px-500px), and have a scrollbar to browse through it.

I have no idea where to start, does anyone has some articles/how-tos or give me directions on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is specify the `height` of your container and the `overflow` method:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work
HTML

```
<div id="main_div">

     // Your contents

</div>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    #main_div {
      width:200px;
      height:400px;
      overflow:scroll;
    }
    // stylish scroll bar
    #main_div{
       overflow: scroll;
    }
    #main_div::-webkit-scrollbar {
        background: transparent;
        height: 4px;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 4px;
    }
    #main_div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    }
    #main_div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);   
    }
    #main_div::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
        background: transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "overflow" property in CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow

This will allow you specify how your outer container handles the size of its content.